# how to fix PF on M3?

Tags: macos, vpn, firewall, wireguard

I have an issue with PF on M3. The VPN connects, but there is no internet access. The VPN configuration and VPN list are identical to another computer (M1). There are no errors upon startup.Does anyone have a solution or is there a problem with my code?!

```
scrub-anchor "com.apple/*"
nat-anchor "com.apple/*"
rdr-anchor "com.apple/*"
dummynet-anchor "com.apple/*"
anchor "com.apple/*"
load anchor "com.apple" from "/etc/pf.anchors/com.apple"
#
set ruleset-optimization basic
set skip on lo0
pass in quick on lo0 all
pass out quick on lo0 all

wifi=en0
ether=en1

# Interfaces
vpn_intf = "{utun0 utun1 utun2 utun3}"

# Table with allowed IPs
table <allowed_vpn_ips> persist file "/etc/pf.anchors/vpn.list"

# Block all outgoing packets
block out all

# Antispoof protection
antispoof for {utun0 utun1 utun2 utun3}

block log proto udp to any port 5353

# Allow DHCP.
pass quick on { $wifi $ether } proto udp from any port 67:68

# Allow outgoing packets to specified IPs only
pass out proto icmp from any to <allowed_vpn_ips>
pass out proto {tcp udp} from any to <allowed_vpn_ips> port {1194 1195 5353 8000 24010 25101 32 500 54563 50000 53 80 443 1194 2049 2050 30587 41893 48574 58237}

# Allow traffic for VPN interfaces
pass out on {utun0 utun1 utun2 utun3} all
```

I tried enabling logging but not figure